# How to select <use> and can be zoomed using svg.pan-zoom.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, svg.js

I use svg.js and svg.pan-zoom.js to make that svg can be zoomed using scroll.
like svg.pan-zoom.js's demo ([this](http://jillix.github.io/svg.pan-zoom.js/))

This is my code, just for test.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="svg.js"></script>
    <script src="svgDraggy.js"></script>
    <script src="svgPanzoom.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #drawing svg {
        width:800px;
        height:400px;
        border:1px solid #333333;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "drawing">
        <svg>
            <g id="canvas">
                 <use xlink:href="space.svg#planet" fill="#19317c"></use>
            </g>

        </svg>
    </div>  

    <script>
        var test = SVG('canvas').panZoom();
        test;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I used 'use' tag, because SVG what I want to use has complicated shape.

Maybe I have mistake svg select in script, but I don't know how to fix it.

Message in console is

> svgPanzoom.js:129 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVG constructor expects a node or an id to a node where the root svg is placed. So in your case it would be `SVG('drawing')`. However - this would not satisfy your needs since it would create a **new** svg document. You want to adopt an inline SVG. To do so, try: `SVG.get('drawing')`. This returns your svg.js instance. Now you can search for your group and call panZoom on it:

```
var svgDoc = SVG.get('drawing')
svgDoc.select('#canvas').get(0).panZoom()
```

Alternatively you can just search directly: `SVG.select('#canvas').get(0).panZoom()`.
In case you want panZoom the whole document I guess you have to call it on the svgDoc directly like: `SVG.get('drawing').panZoom()`

I also suggest to use the official addon [svg.draggable.js](https://github.com/wout/svg.draggable.js) instead of draggy since it handles transformations a lot more stable.